# JqueryUI datepicker - no 'isvisible' property?

Tags: jquery-ui

To anyone who has used the jqueryUi datepicker control -

There are show() and hide() methods, but hopefully im being blind because i cant see any way to query whether or not the datepicker is visible or not?

The only alternative it to write my own which is a messy approach.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
$("#idoftextbox").datepicker("widget").is(":visible")
```